# Mysql Master Master Replication Issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am implementing master master replication in mysql.
I can do it successfully but have a doubt.

For my case, there are two solution
1. To use one master for failover cases only. (i dont recommend)
2. Distribute load by changing application (like it)

**Issue i found in any of two approach.**

We have two masters A and B. Now User update city to Delhi and it goes to server A and before B replicate this query server A goes down and we shift all queries to server B only. Then same user updates city to Mumbai.
Now when server A goes up, 
* delhi update query will go to server B (bin log reading)
* Mumbai update query will go to server A (bin log reading)

Hence discrepancy in data.

How to solve this issue ?

My database is mix of innodb and myisam

Comment: My understanding of a master-master setup is that Server A and Server B have to ack all commits, otherwise the update will fail and you must handle the broken setup first. Therefore you can't have any inconsistency. You also can consider the Galera protocol (Percona or MariaDB): http://galeracluster.com/products/

Comment: @s.meissner we cant do Synchronous replication as we tables are mix of innodb and myisam

Answer (score 0):

I guess (not tested) you can achieve this with a Proxy, e.g. [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale)

Configure the proxy with readsplit to distrubutes reads over Server A and B and only one Master for the rest. In addition setup a Master Failover Scenario when Server A goes down.

Actually you have a simple Master-Slave Setup in MaxScale, but in the background there is still the Master-Master working. MaxScale or your application doesn't need to know this.

Comment: can i do it without using proxy

Comment: I dont think so. If you have a multi master setup you cant have a conflict-free replication (as you point out). You have to use a Cluster instead. The only way I see as a workaround is to use the multi master setup in a master-slave like way. But than I would recommend to use a true master-slave setup.

Comment: master slave wont' help as i need to divide load as well.

Comment: You can not have both with a Master-Master replication: HA with Failover + Write scaling. If you really need this you have to setup a Cluster.